# Handling Events for Many Elements (Problems)

Tags: javascript, php, loops, while-loop

Okay so i have done alot of rewriting to eliminate loops that adds eventlisteners..

[This link explains -> Handling Events for Many Elements](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)

But this way will give me some problems... basically how do i add an eventListener to every edit label generated? (see php code)
I can do this by making a loop that adds an event listener to every label but aparently this is bad practice?

Right now my "parent" element is `<div id="popUp">` this makes the popup appear when the whole code inside `<div class="col100 pad10 flex editUsers"></div>` is clicked not just the "edit label"...
And how could i dynamically add the correct form information if i want to loadup a form in the popup?

PHP LOOP

```
<div id="popUp">
<?php
$stmt = $dbCon->prepare(" SELECT id, username, level "
        . " FROM bilbixen_login ");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $username, $level);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    ?>
    <div class="col100 pad10 flex editUsers">
        <div class="col80">
            <p>User : <?php echo $username; ?></p>
            <p>Level : <?php echo $level; ?></p>
        </div>
        <form class="" action="#" method="POST">
            <input class="" id="submitDelete<?php echo $id; ?>" type="radio" name="status" value="0">
            <input class="" id="submitAccept<?php echo $id; ?>" type="radio" name="status" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="userId">
            <input id="submit<?php echo $id; ?>" type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
        <div class="flex col20 space-b">
            <label for="submitDelete<?php echo $id; ?>" class="pad10 bgcr pointer">Delete</label>
            <label for="submitAccept<?php echo $id; ?>" class="pad10 bgcg pointer">Edit</label>
            <label for="submit<?php echo $id; ?>" class="pad10 bgcb pointer">Submit</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
$stmt->close();
?>
</div>
```

Javascript/Popup

```
<script>
    var popUp = document.querySelector('#popUp');
    var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    var close = document.getElementById('close');

    popUp.addEventListener("click", doSomething, false);

    function doSomething(e) {
        if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
            overlay.style.display = 'block';
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    close.addEventListener('click', function () {
        overlay.style.display = 'none';
    });
    window.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        if (event.target === overlay) {
            overlay.style.display = "none";
        }
        ;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Give `submitDelete` and `submitAccept` a class (both the same class), then add an event-listener  for that class. In the listener you can check via `attr('id')`(jquery version) witch element was clicked. So you need only one event-listener for all. BTW: You should use jQuery makes all simpler https://api.jquery.com/

Comment: doSomething should check which element was clicked and only set the display to block if the target is one of the edit labels. Also `.attr()` = `.getAttribute()`. If you have managed to code without JQuery, keep it that way, since it's easy to create slow code in jquery.

Comment: I only code in vanilla Js :) we are taught by our professors never to use jQuery :) but its a bit confusing this part since i used to just loop classes through and add event listeners -.-'